# MySQL Left Join (I think)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i got into a problem. I have 3 tables, I join them but cant get the right answer, if anyone could help me, I would appreciate it. So what i want is, for Answer to show me unused Materials. Tables: [image]

With a lot of help I got all the unused materials with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Materials.Material_Name) AS Unused_materials FROM Materials
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Material_Number = Materials.Material_Number
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Procedure_Name = Table2.Procedure_Name
WHERE Table1.Procedure_Name IS NULL
```

**UPDATED:**
If I may ask one more question in the same post. Maybe anyone would know how to get the above information, just with the Wanted Day. Like: Unused materials in 2012-11-20?

Comment: selecting null selects null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johan above almost has it (unused materials will still exist in table_2, since Table2 is just a lookup of Procedure_Name to Material_Number (which if it's a 1:1 relationship seems like a silly addition). Still need to join against Table1 to get the null values.

so

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM Materials c 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON b.Material_Number = c.Material_Number
        LEFT JOIN Table1 a ON a.Procedure_Name = b.Procedure_Name
  WHERE a.Procedure_Name is null;
```

All commands for repeat comparison:

```
create table Table1 (Procedure_Name char, date date);
create table Table2 (Procedure_Name char, Material_Number int);
create table Materials (Material_Name varchar(12), Material_Number int);

insert into Table1 values ('A', '2012-11-22');
insert into Table1 values ('B', '2012-11-21');
insert into Table1 values ('C', '2012-11-20');

insert into Table2 values ('A', '101');
insert into Table2 values ('B', '102');
insert into Table2 values ('C', '103');
insert into Table2 values ('D', '104');
insert into Table2 values ('E', '105');

insert into Materials values ('Iron', 101);
insert into Materials values ('Steel', 102);
insert into Materials values ('Wood', 103);
insert into Materials values ('Glass', 104);
insert into Materials values ('Sand', 105);

-- johan query
SELECT Material_Name
FROM Materials M
LEFT JOIN Table2 T ON M.Material_Number = T.Material_Number
WHERE Procedure_Name IS NULL;

-- my query
select Material_Name
  from Materials c
  left join Table2 b on b.Material_Number = c.Material_Number
  left join Table1 a on a.Procedure_Name = b.Procedure_name
 where a.Procedure_Name is null;
```

Comment: This query makes me cringe a bit -- two unnecessary joins!  I guess performance is not an issue!  The NOT IN operator is designed precisely to answer the question the user asked!

Comment: I'd recommend you try my query before claiming I have it "almost right". One left join is enough - the second is completely unnecessary. But you will obviously have to change your a.Procedue_Name to b.Procedure_Name - or simply remove the table qualifier.

Comment: Thanks for help, the one with 2 LEFT JOIN helped :) But thanks Everyone for spending time to help ^^

Comment: @johanmartensson I did try your query, and wasn't able to get the results the user was requesting.

Comment: I included the full set of command to recreate the tables and test both my and Johan's query.

Comment: Yes, i try'ed both of them and as I have mentioned earlier the one with 2 LEFT JOINS worked for me, other didin't showed what i wanted :)

Comment: The comment was more for the other users answering, and my own education. I'm not sure if I'm missing something that they're suggesting, but to my understanding joining Materials against Table2 and expecting the Procuedure_Name to be Null will never happen with the data provided.

Likewise with the WHERE NOT IN below. If Table1 and Table2 were merged together to be one table, either of those solutions would likely work the way I'd expect.

Comment: @svarog - due to excessive commenting, I've seen this post several times. We had a misunderstanding on the requirement.  I see now that both tables are necessary.  I am revising my NOT IN answer to take into account that there must be an entry in Table1 related to a material in Table 2.  Good catch on the requirement!

Answer (score 3):

Joining in Table1 and Table2 as you have it will only give you rows for used materials.  What you want to do is select all materials that have NOT BEEN used.  To do this, simply use the NOT IN construct with a sub-query:

```
SELECT Material_Name AS Unused_materials
FROM Materials
WHERE Materials.Material_Number
    NOT IN (SELECT Material_Number FROM Table2)
```

**Update:** Now that I understand the data model (only wanting materials that have NOT been used in a procedure listed in Table1), here is the correct query to use if using NOT IN construct for the query:

```
SELECT Material_Name AS Unused_materials
FROM Materials
WHERE Materials.Material_Number
    NOT IN (SELECT Material_Number FROM Table2
             INNER JOIN Table1
                ON Table1.Procedure_Name = Table2.Procedure_Name)
```

Comment: While the query optimizer could potentially turn this into something equally efficient as when using a LEFT JOIN, mysql will not. Run explain on both your query and mine, and you will see the difference. This will execute one subquery for every row found in the primary query. Gernal advive: stay away from (NOT) EXISTS and (NOT) IN

Comment: @johanmårtensson - That would surprise me as I am relying on past experience in other database technologies.  I'll have to check this out more!

Comment: @johanmårtensson - This article seems to be good analysis for these queries: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/  I am still of the mind that NOT IN would be equal (if not better) performance than doing the join assuming properly indexed tables.  The advice to stay away from NOT IN seems unfounded, however, the linked article does warn about NOT EXISTS!  I'll have to keep this in mind next time I have a mysql project.

Comment: Indeed I had mixed these up. Or rather, I had wrongly assumed that NOT IN and NOT EXISTS would lead to the same execution plan. They don't - and it's easy to reach  this conclusion when I think about it.You are also correct in that the NOT IN is faster (a lot!). Feel free to downvote my solution since it is a lot slower. And therefor bad.

Comment: Why to downvote? If you learn something or you try to help others I still appreciate Your work :)

Comment: I never down-vote unless something is truly atrocious and needs down-voting. Your solution is 100% valid, but your reasoning was misinformed, so no down-vote from me!  The follow-up discussion in comments is often very informative...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: 
Disregard this solution. I'm leaving it up for the sake of having the complete discussion. Or woukd it be customary to remove this answer?

After comment-discussion under David Fleeman's solution, I did some profiling and the short answer is: go with David Fleemans solution, using NOT IN. It will be faster than the left join solution.

Do use David Fleemans solution

Original post
The reason you will never get anything but an empty resultset using that query is that you are selecting material_name and also specify that material_name should be null…

All used materials will have entries in Table2. All unused materials will lack such entries. Therefor, select from Materials, left join with Table2 and add condition that procedure name is null.

```
SELECT Material_Name
FROM Materials M
LEFT JOIN Table2 T ON M.Material_Number = T.Material_Number
WHERE Procedure_Name IS NULL
```